# Why does an a:link in one div affect the a:link in another?

Tags: css, html, styles

I'm working with a content div and a footer div. I have different anchor styles for each div. For some reason, my content anchors are taking the style from my footer anchors, and I cannot for the *life* of me figure out why!

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="content">
  <h1>WELCOME</h1>
  <p>Content content content. Click <a href="index.html">here</a> for more information.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <p><a href="index.html">Home</a> &mdash; <a href="">Printable Forms</a> &mdash; <a href="">Ad Rates</a> &mdash; <a href="">Contact Us</a></p>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
body
{

  background-color: #c8d3fc;
  color: black;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  font-size: 12pt;

}


.content
{

  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 261px;
  width: 827px;
  background: url('../images/contentBG.jpg') repeat-y;

}


.content a:link, a:visited, a:active
{

  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;

}


.content a:hover
{

  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff9e00;
  font-weight: bold;

}


.footer
{

  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 261px;
  width: 827px;
  height: 78px;
  background: url('../images/footerBG.jpg');
  color: white;

}


.footer a:link, a:visited, a:active
{

  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;

}


.footer a:hover
{

  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff9e00;

}
```

So even though my body has default color of black and my a:link etc. styles for my content div are specifically set to black, the links in the content div show up as white. If I change the a:link etc. styles for the footer div to black, it will change both the footer and content links to black, but I need the footer to be white. I've tried putting the "color: black;" in the content div directly, but that didn't help. The a:hover styling and everything else works perfectly. What really kills me is the code works fine in IE, but not FF. I write really simple code and it feels like there's probably a really simple solution, but I just cannot figure it out, so any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: They show up just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/6QqM7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with your selectors.

```
.content a:link, a:visited, a:active {}
```

Should be:

```
.content a:link, .content a:visited, .content a:active {}
```

And the same for the footer links:

```
.footer a:link, .footer a:visited, .footer a:active {}
```

Comment: That was it exactly. Arg, I knew it would be something simple! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

> .content a:link, a:visited, a:active

will apply to all `a:visited` and `a:active` and only `.content a:link`. If you are using commas, you must refer to them again ..

So change

> .content a:link, a:visited, a:active

to

> .content a:link, .content  a:visited, .content  a:active

and

> .footer a:link, a:visited, a:active

to

> .footer a:link, .footer  a:visited, .footer  a:active